# Make a streamlit web app use a chromedriver.exe file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, selenium-chromedriver, streamlit

I'd like to deploy my web app through the streamlit community cloud but I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/corners-betting/CornersBetting.py", line 17, in <module>
    mws = import_MyWebScrapingTools().MyWsTools()
File "MyWebscrapingTools.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.driver = init_driver()
File "MyWebscrapingTools.py", line 25, in init_driver
    chrome_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url
    driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download()
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
```

The app should perform some actions of webscraping with Selenium but to do so it need to execute a chromedriver.exe file.
I tried two ways to do it:

1. Upload the latest chromdriver.exe in the GitHub repo and use [the GitHub link](https://github.com/LeonardoAcquaroli/corners-betting/blob/main/chromedriver.exe) as *executable_path* in *webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)* **FAILS TO READ IT**
2. Use *Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())* and try to automatically install the latest *chromedriver.exe* at any run. **FAILS WITH THE ABOVE ERROR (and a question...where should install it?)**

This is the [link to the GitHub page](https://github.com/LeonardoAcquaroli/corners-betting/tree/main). (Note that I use a custom module to speed up some webscraping actions but it's just some functions built on top of selenium).

I got that since the streamlit cloud environment runs on a Linux Debian system, Windows .exe can't be installed but do you know any solution or workaround?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a Streamlit web app in an environment like Streamlit Cloud, which typically runs on a Linux-based system, using a Windows executable like chromedriver.exe can be challenging. However, you can use a headless browser like Firefox (Geckodriver) with Selenium to perform web scraping actions in a cross-platform manner.
Install Geckodriver:

You'll need to download and install Geckodriver, which is the WebDriver for Firefox. You can download it from the official website:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Choose the appropriate version for your operating system. Since Streamlit Cloud runs on Linux, download the Linux version.
Extract the downloaded file and place it in a directory accessible by your Streamlit app.
Modify Your Streamlit App Code:

Modify your Streamlit app code to use the Firefox WebDriver instead of Chrome. Here's an example of how to set up a Selenium WebDriver with Firefox in your Streamlit app:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

## Set the path to the Geckodriver executable

geckodriver_path = '/path/to/geckodriver'

## Create a Firefox WebDriver instance

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver_path)

## Now you can use 'driver' for web scraping with Firefox.

Make sure to replace '/path/to/geckodriver' with the actual path to the Geckodriver executable on your Streamlit Cloud environment.

Deploy Your Streamlit App:

Deploy your modified Streamlit app, ensuring that the Geckodriver executable is in the correct location on the deployment environment (Streamlit Cloud).
By using Geckodriver and Firefox, you can perform web scraping actions within your Streamlit app in a cross-platform and compatible manner without relying on Windows-specific executables like chromedriver.exe.

Comment: Thanks so much for the alternative solution. How can I check what the path to Geckodriver exe in the Streamlit cloud environment is?

Comment: from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

geckodriver_path = GeckoDriverManager().install()
print("Geckodriver path:", geckodriver_path)

Use this Python code to check the path 
install this package with this command 

pip install webdriver-manager

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I managed to use webdriver on streamlit thanks to this answer: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/make-a-streamlit-web-app-use-a-chromedriver-exe-file/53473/13.
Now I still have a new issue with loading the webpages headless. Taking a look here is so much appreciated: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/make-a-streamlit-web-app-use-a-chromedriver-exe-file/53473/13

Comment: I think the issue you're facing might be related to the dynamic loading of elements on the web page.


 the solution to address the timeout issue with Selenium is to use explicit waits with expected conditions. This ensures that Selenium waits for the specific element to be present, visible, or clickable before attempting to interact with it. This helps synchronize your script with the loading of the web page elements.